# How to collect data from two seperate timeframe under one indicator on Pinescript v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to copy my script, change the values and merge them under one indicator.
I can do it by myself but I have one problem. If I start like this;

```
//@version=5
//First Indicator
indicator(title="First Indicator", shorttitle="First Indicator", format=format.price, timeframe="D", timeframe_gaps=true)
```

The second part of the indicator is effected as well.

I want the first part will plot ''daily'', and the second part will use ''weekly'' period to plot the line.
Whatever timeframe I select, I want the the first indicator will use 'daily' info and second one will use 'weekly' info.

What should I add to the script. Can anyone help?
ı tried this but I couldn't make it.
timeFrame = request.security (symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe = "D", expression = close)

Comment: You'll need to share your code if you want help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
indicator(title="First Indicator", overlay = true)

dayly_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)
weekly_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', close)
```

and then just use variables dayly_close and weekly_close at any timeframe